# Prove, by giving an example , Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove, by giving an example, that, if n is not prime, a≠0(mod n) then it is not necessarily true that { [1]n,[2]n.........[n-1]n} = {[a.1]n,[a.2]n,.......[a.(n-1)]n}

could you give me any hint to solve that I try many examples but all of them without usefulness I found the congruence class equal.

Comment: Try n=4 and a=2

Comment: Your notation is a little confusing. To help me understand, can you tell me what "{[1]5, [2]5, ......... [4]5}" equals?

Comment: [1]5 it means 1 mod 5

Comment: Okay, that helps, but this is still confusing. "[a.1]n" means $a \times 1 \bmod n$ or does it mean something else entirely?